# Change Icon/Text placement on Tab bar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I want to show the Text next to Icon on tab bar on Landscape view. It looks correct on Storyboard as shown below:
[image]

But it does not in the simulator or real device. The Text is still stacked with Icon like this:
[image]

Is it something we can configure?

Comment: It should work out of the box. Why isn't your first item (tab[0]) shown? And why is there green background on the left in the second picture?

Comment: Isn't it a bit paranoid to gray out the name of the tab bar controller? :D I mean.. what could possibly be there worth protecting? "Twitter Tab Bar Controller", "Snapchat Tab Bar Controller"? - I'm not judging, it's just funny to me ;)

Comment: Just wanted to keep some privacy. :-) I actually don't know whey the first  item is missing on the storyboard, but it's shown when I run it, the green means the the first tab is selected. (Again I hide the tab name for whatever reason) I hope it still makes question clear. Now back to my question again? If it works out of the box, then why it does not at least on some devices.

Comment: What's your Xcode version? I vaguely remember iPhone X not having  `verticalSizeClass == .compact` in landscape in some earlier versions of Xcode 9.

Comment: Additionally, do you hook the tab bar class and override `layoutSubviews()` or anything of that sort?

Comment: @Cabus I use Xcode 9.2. I have tabBarController, which overrides viewDidAppear and viewWillTransition. What they do is basically set the selectionIndicatorImage (i.e., set the background of selected tab to be green.) I noticed that there is LaunchScreen.storyboard before Main.storyboard. The text actually shows next to Icon on the Launchscreen, then when it gets into the main view, it's reset to stack tab bar. Sorry that I am new to IOS, and the code was set up by previous developer. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?